# Is there a benefit to rendering my React app from my express server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm reading a lot about rendering a React app from an express server and I'm just curious what the benefit would be to doing that?

I've already completed a React app and used an express server to interact with my db. I'd start my express server and then npm start my react app (which runs on localMachine:3000). When I'd want to interact with my db I would just fetch to the express address (i.e. localMachine:4000) with the appropriate route. It functions fine that way so as I begin to build the backend of another app I would just like know if there is a reason to not do it that way.

I don't know a lot about express so thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Well you don't have to configure other servers like apache or nginx to serve static content ,you can just simply reverse proxy request to backend node server ,also your backend and frontend will be at the same origin

Answer (score 0):

when you deploy your react app, you still need a server to serve your react application if your app is dynamic.

Netlify or github hosts only static react apps. But if your app is dynamic, you create an express server that serves your app and you can deploy it on heroku